# Can I test setInterval with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, clock

I have this statement in my code, and I was wondering how I could test the setInterval using Jasmine.

```
const x = setInterval(() => {
    const countdown = getElementById('countdownWrapper');
    const systemTime = ...
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const endTime = systemTime - now;

    countdown.querySelector('.countdown-time').innerHTML = time();

    if (endTime < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        countdown.classList.remove('countdown-time--show');
    }
}, 1000);
```

systemTime is fed from an epoch value in a DATA-CONTENT attribute in the HTML.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How jasmine clock works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889562/how-jasmine-clock-works)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
beforeEach(function() {
  timerCallback = jasmine.createSpyObj("setInterval");
  jasmine.clock().install();
});

afterEach(function() {
  jasmine.clock().uninstall();
});

it("causes a timeout to be called", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    timerCallback();
  }, 1000);

  expect(setInterval).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

  jasmine.clock().tick(1001);

  expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Where would I call the code I am testing, as I have tried it in the beforeEach before the SpyOn, I have also created `let timerCallback` before the beforeEach, but I am still getting `createSpyObj requires a non-empty array or object of method names to create spies for thrown. Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.` This sounds like the function isn't firing

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the help, but at which point do I call my script to test? I've placed it in the beforeEach, but I am getting this error

`createSpyObj requires a non-empty array or object of method names to create spies for thrown
     Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: I am using Headless Chrome to run the unit tests, would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Correction to Benny's answer:

```
timerCallback = jasmine.createSpyObj("test", {setInterval: 0});
AND
expect(timerCallback.setInterval).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Also, this DOESN'T test setInterval, that's been mocked here. This tests setTimeout!